# How Can I add row in google sheet when I Create a New Folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

How Can I add row in google sheet when I Create a New Folder in Google Drive?

I have folder in google drive
and I need when I create a new folder inside it create a new last row in google spreadsheet and add hyperlink with new folder name in column E and the local date created in column G and the parent folder name in column M